# Slicing matrix in for loop with index in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3D matrix such as:

```
array([[[3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [12., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

I want to slice this in [: , 0, :], [-1,: :].. and all 6 directions in the order with a for loop. So for each dimension, slicing from the first (0) and last (-1).

What is the proper way of applying the for loop?

Lets assume the name of the array is `A`:

```
A[0, :, :]
A[:, :, 0]
A[:, 0, :]
A[-1, :, :]
A[:, -1, :]
A[:, :, -1]
```

I want to have these 6 submatrices (lets say in a list) in one loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "all 6 directions" and "in the order"? It might help if you give an example of the output you expect.

Comment: You almost never need loops with NumPy. The best answer is very unlikely to involve loops. It would help if you show what output you expect from your input?

Comment: This is a (3,3,3) shaped array.  You need to be more explicit about what you want to do - examples of the resulting slices.  Often the action is clearer if you use an array like `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` - distinct dimensions, and values.

Comment: edited the questions to make it a bit clearer. Reshaping is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear at all *why* you want to do this, but you can dynamically snatch subarrays using [`take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2, 3, 4)  # dummy input

arrays = [arr.take(index, axis) for axis in range(arr.ndim) for index in [0,-1]]
```

This list of arrays will contain `arr[0,:,:]`, `arr[-1,:,:]`, `arr[:,0,:]`, `arr[:,-1,:]` etc. in this order. Here's proof for a single element in the list of arrays:

```
>>> np.array_equal(arr[:,-1,:], arr.take(-1, 1))
True
```

Your question wasn't too specific about the order, but the above can easily be generalized for an arbitrary ordering of your slicing requirements:

```
indices = [0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1]
axes = [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
arrays = [arr.take(index, axis) for index,axis in zip(indices, axes)]
```

This matches the order of the subarrays as specified in your question.